# Is there an analogue of Alexander's Theorem for Brunnian braids/links?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, knot-theory, braid-groups

The [Alexander's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander%27s_theorem) says that every knot or link can be represented as a closed braid. Is it true that every Brunnian link can be represented as a closed Brunnian Braid?

My guess is that the answer is No. Any counterexamples?

A braid is called *Brunnian* if removing any of its strings results in the trivial braid. Similarly a link is called *Brunnian* if removing any of its components results in the trivial link.